# Hyphen (-) in string bound to text input control in GridView with Eval("columnName") cuts off the text after the hyphen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView which is bound to a data source. In the .aspx file I use somthing like this

```
<asp:GridView...>
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                      <input type="text" value='<%# Eval('type') %>'
...
</GridView>
```

What happens is, when type="Rock'n'Roll - guitar" for example, after databinding the text in the input is cut off before the hyphen and on, so whats left is "Rock'n'Roll"

This also happend for the quotes ('), and i tried using

```
<input type="text" value='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval('type').ToString()) %>'
```

which solved the issue with quote sign in the string but still have the issue with hyphen.

Any ideas? 
thanx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Server.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doesn't encode apostrophes.  Could you try surrounding the attribute with double quotes:

```
<input type="text" value="<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval('type').ToString()) %>" />
```

I suspect this hyphen issue is the result of the apostrophes in the value making the attribute go wacky.

Comment: if i use double quotes from outside and single quotes inside i get a compiler error:

CS1012: Too many characters in character literal.

this is so frustrating... but thanx anyway

Comment: What happens if you also change the `'Eval'` to `"Eval"`? Any difference?

Comment: its the same. i mean, i dont get the error, but the text in the input field is cut off after the hyphen...

Comment: Could you try doing View Source in your browser and see what it shows there for that part of the page?

Comment: the value attribute of the input fields is just showing the text before the hyphen character (like in my description post, if the string to be bound is "Rock'n'roll - guitar" the value attribute is set to "Rock'n'roll")

If I manually try to change the text of the input field in the console using JavaScript/jQuery, then all text is shown including the hyphens and the text after the hyphens....

Answer (score 0):

this is working perfectly fine

**Eval("type") insted of Eval('type')**
Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
           <ItemTemplate>
                  <input type="text" value='<%#  Server.HtmlEncode( Eval("type").ToString()) %>' />
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind for demo

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string)); 
        dt.Rows.Add("Rock'n'Roll - guitar");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing   `ItemStyle-Wrap="false"`.  I had a problem with negative number doing the same thing.